A property of an irreducible root system
Let $\Phi$ be an irreducible root system. Let $\alpha_k$ be a simple root. I recently observed that the number of positive roots which are bigger than $\alpha_k$ and of height $m$ is same as the number of positive roots bigger than $\alpha_k$ and of height $h-m-1$, where $h$ is the coxeter number of $\Phi$ which is just one more than the height of the highest root. Is there an uniform proof of this statement ?

Should your $h-k-1$ be $h-m-1$, or rather $h-m$?

Sorry for the typo. It should be $h-m-1$ as the highest root is the unique positive root of height $h-1$.

I still think it should be $h-m$. In type A1, $h=2$ and after choosing one of the roots as simple, there is only that one, of height $1=m=h-m$. In type A2, $h=3$ and after choosing simple roots $\alpha,\beta$, there is e.g. one bigger or equal $\alpha$ ($\alpha$ itself), of height $1=m$, and there is one bigger or equal $\alpha$ of height $h-m=2$, namely $\alpha+\beta$. No other heights occur. Or what is your definition of height? Simple roots have height 1, no?

It is $h-m-1$. For example if you take the $D_5$ root system, then $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_2+\alpha_3$ are the two roots of height 2 and bigger than $\alpha_2$. However, there is only one root of height $h-2=6$, namely, $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+2\alpha_3+\alpha_4+\alpha_5$. There are two roots of height 5.

Well then the formula is false in type A2 for $m=2$. So there cannot be a proof.

$A_2$ is the only case where for $m=2$, we have $h-m-1=0$ and it doesn't make sense to talk about height zero elements. Apart from this trivial case the statement is true.

So are you saying the statement holds for each $m$ with $1 \le m \le h-2$?

Yes. That is true.

For type $A_3$ I have $h=4$, but if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2, \alpha_3$ are a basis in standard ordering, then for roots bigger than $\alpha_2$ there is one of height 1, two of height 2. So the claim is still false for $m=1$ and for $m=2$. For $\alpha_2$ in $A_4$ I see one of height 1, two of height 2, two of height 3, one of height 4 = $h-1$. The formula with h-m-1 gives wrong results, while h-m would fit so far.
